# How to connect 1010DATA using SSIS

Tags: ssis-2012

I have requirement like source data is available at 1010database and I need to extract the same to SQL server table.

Can you please let me know the how to connect 1010database to extract the data from SSIS.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to migrate data out of 1010data into an SSIS workflow you're going to want to use 1010data's [ODBC driver](https://1010data.com/downloads/odbc/windows/odbcsetup.exe) (documentation [here](https://www.1010data.com/downloads/odbc/doc/))

If you're trying to migrate data from an SSIS workflow into 1010data you'll want to use [tenup](https://www.1010data.com/downloads/tenup/tenup.zip) (documentation [here](https://www.1010data.com/downloads/tenup/doc/))